# Python: decorator for mocking gettext during testing

Tags: python, unit-testing, testing, decorator, python-decorators

I'm writing a Django app, and I wanted to write a decorator that will mock the `_()` function during testing, just adding '_translated' after the string to translate

I basically have my decorator to replace the following instruction within my test:

```
with mock.patch('module_which_is_being_tested._', lambda s: s+'_translated'):
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I didn't find anything similar on the web, so I'm sharing it:

```
from unittest import mock
import functools

def mock_translation(tested_object):
    """
    A decorator that mock the '_()' function during testing
    just adds '_translated' after the string to translate

    the class/function being tested needs to be passed as parameter

    Use: 
    from my_module.sub_module import my_function_to_be_tested

    @mock_translation(my_function_to_be_tested)
    def test_my_function_to_be_tested():
        pass
    """
 
    def actual_decorator(func):
        @functools.wraps(func)
        def wrapper(*args, **kwargs):
            module_name = tested_object.__module__
            tested_obj = tested_object
            breakpoint()
            import_path = module_name + '._'
            # with mock.patch('battletech.models._', lambda s: s+'_translated'):
            with mock.patch(import_path, lambda s: s+'_translated'):
                value = func(*args, **kwargs)
                return value
        return wrapper
    return actual_decorator
```